# Android Studio: How to use ViewPagerAdapter on Multiple Buttons to load different images?

Tags: android-studio

I am new to coding and I am stuck with something. I have a set of 5 slideshows with about 30 images for each. I have an activity with 5 buttons. I am using a ViewPagerAdapter to load the slides from my drawable folder. All is working for the first button using the code I am posting here. The code loads all ~30 images to make the slideshow. Now When I try to make a new ViewPagerAdapter (couldn't make a duplicate name so i renamed it ViewPagerAdapterBD. Not sure if this is wrong) for the second button to load different files from the drawable, the class in the code is grayed out saying "ViewPagerAdapterBD is never used". I continued to load the new images but the second button would still load the files from the first button. My question is, how can I have my 5 buttons open up different images from my drawable folder? What do I need to do to have my buttons open up different images to ultimately have each button display a different slideshow for each? Or better wording, I want to know how to go about using an imageslider on different activities using viewpageradapter?

BurstMode.java

```
 import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 public class BurstMode extends AppCompatActivity {
 ViewPager viewPager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_burst_mode);


    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Burst Mode");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

   viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
 ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this);
 viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

}
}
```

activity_burst_mode.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".BurstMode">

 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:id="@+id/viewPager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

ViewPagerAdapter.java

```
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
 import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
 import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.ImageView;

 public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {


private Context context;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private Integer [] images = {R.drawable.bm1,R.drawable.bm2,R.drawable.bm3,
        R.drawable.bm4,R.drawable.bm5,R.drawable.bm6,R.drawable.bm7,
        R.drawable.bm8,R.drawable.bm8,R.drawable.bm10,R.drawable.bm11,
        R.drawable.bm12,R.drawable.bm13,R.drawable.bm14,R.drawable.bm15,
        R.drawable.bm16,R.drawable.bm17,R.drawable.bm18,R.drawable.bm19,
        R.drawable.bm20,R.drawable.bm21,R.drawable.bm22,R.drawable.bm23,
        R.drawable.bm24,R.drawable.bm26,R.drawable.bm27,R.drawable.bm28,
        R.drawable.bm29,R.drawable.bm30,R.drawable.bm31};


public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return images.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object o) {
    return view == o;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)           
 context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout_burst_mode, 
 null);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);

    ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
    vp.addView(view,0);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull 
 Object object) {

    ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
    View view = (View) object;
    vp.removeView(view);
}


  }
```

custom_layout_burst_mode.xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_off"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="164dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="65dp" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Here is an image of the activity with the buttons: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAdtW.jpg)

I want to know how I can go about having each button open up different sets of images, different from the other buttons

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to programming!

Go ahead and scrap the other class, ViewPagerAdapterBD. Instead, let's extend the other class you already wrote.

Consider the constructor for ViewPagerAdapter.

```
public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

Why not pass in an argument here which configures it to behave differently?

```
public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, SlideShowType type) {
    this.context = context
    this.type = type
}
```

Go ahead and look up *enumerated types* in Java, it will help you create this SlideShowType enum. Once you've done that, your adapter can check this configuration in a switch statement, and make use of different arrays of images depending on the SlideShowType passed into the constructor!

Another option would be passing the array of image resources into the constructor directly. Let me know if you'd like me to follow up with more detail on anything.